# Component tag does not render blazor component when the razor page is not directly in the pages folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, components, blazor

I an trying to render a blazor component in a razor page. My project is ASP.NET Core Web App. I am primarily using razor pages. I have been successful rendering a blazor component when the razor page is in the Pages folder such as in the Privacy page, but when I added a razor page to a subfolder in the Pages folder, it does not work anymore.

I have been following this link. It works. Just not when the razor page is in a folder within the Pages folder.
[Using Blazor Components In An Existing MVC Application](https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/)

This is my cshtml code.

```
<component type="typeof(HelloWorld.Pages.Components.Counter)" render-mode="Server" />
```

Comment: It doesn't render anything. It just shows the privacy page.

Comment: Update: Changing the render-mode to static shows the button now, but it is static and not responsive.

Comment: Found a different solution. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the blazor script on each page, I added two things in the _Layout.cshtml page.

In the head tag

```
<base href="~/" /> 
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server" />
```

Below the footer tag

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```